# Is it save to skip the first (.) and second value (..) of PHPs scandir function when searching for files or directories?

Tags: php, scandir

I'm actually asking this myself for years now:
**is it save to skip the first and second value of an array fetched by `scandir`?**

By now I'm iterating over an array fetched by `scandir` (more or less) like this:

```
for ( $scan = scandir('path/to/dir/'), $i = 0, $c = count( $scan ); $i < $c; ++$i )
{
    if ( $scan[ $i ][ 0 ] != '.' )
    {
        // $scan[ $i ] is file name or dir name
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine as well but seems to be redundant if `$scan[ 0 ][ 0 ]` is always `.` and `$scan[ 1 ][ 0 ]` is always `..`.

So would it be save to skip the first and second value like this:

```
for ( $scan = scandir('path/to/dir/'), $i = 2/* starting with 2 instead of 0 */, $c = count( $scan ); $i < $c; ++$i )
{
    // $scan[ $i ] is file name or dir name
}
```

When I `var_dump` a `scandir` I always get and got a structure like this:

```
var_dump( scandir('path/to/dir/') );
array(
    0 => '.',  // is this the case for each
    1 => '..', // and every environment
    2 => 'filename.ext',
    [...]
)
```

But I'm mostly working in my own server environment and haven't seen too much different server environments. So can I be sure that in each and every environment (OS, PHP version, etc.) I will find a structure fetched by `scandir` that will look similar like the one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot safely assume that `.` and `..` will be returned first.

By default, the results from `scandir()` are returned in alphabetical order, as if the result had been passed to `sort()`. However, there are characters that will sort above `.` -- for instance, a file named `!README` will be returned before `.`.

If you want to skip these entries, check for them explicitly, e.g.

```
foreach (scandir("path/to/dir") as $file) {
    if ($file === "." || $file === "..")
        continue;

    // do stuff with $file
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: `.`, `..` are standing what for in this context?

Comment: Current directory and parent directory, respectively. Just like they do in paths.